# Float transparent PNG over text

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am looking to add semi-transparent stamp type image over a particular part of the text.
We are using vue to build our new website.

I've not really found anything about how to do this in vue.

I'm looking to place the image over the 4th line of the code shown below. Basically what it does is display the 'Report accepted by:' text along with the person who accepted the report taken from the database. I'd like to display that with an overlapping image that resembles a stamp of approval.

[image]

```
  <template>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <span>Report accepted by:</span>
    <span v-if="report_info.accepted && report_info.accepted_by !== null">{{ memberById(report_info.accepted_by).callsign }}</span>
    <button
      v-if="isAdmin"
      class="float-right"
      v-on:click="acceptRejectReport"
    >{{ acceptButtonText }}</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import { mapState, mapGetters } from "vuex"

export default {
  name: "ReportApprovalComp",
  mounted ()  {

    this.checkAdmin();
  },
  data () {
    return {

      isAdmin: false
    }
  },
  computed: {

    acceptButtonText() {

      if(this.report_info.accepted){
        return "Revoke report acceptance";
      } else {
        return "Approve report";
      }
    },

    ...mapState("missionStore", {
      report_info: state => state.report,
    }),

    ...mapGetters("missionStore", [
      "memberById"
    ])
  },
  methods: {

    checkAdmin: async function () {

      this.isAdmin = await this.$auth.isAdmin(this.$options.name);
    },

    acceptRejectReport: async function () {

      this.$store.dispatch('missionStore/acceptRejectReport',
        {
          caller: this.$options.name,
          member_id: await this.$auth.getUserId(),
        });
    }
  }

}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Could you rework your example to include some "fake" data so it can be run in isolation? It would make it easier to see what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Added the output to the OP. I want a stamp PNG image to appear over the name of the person accepting it, in this case 'Onebad'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

already has the logic ... you just need to actually provide your img element as the last child inside that span. Your span will need to have css position:relative and your img needs css position:absolute;top:0;right:0; ... you might need display:inline-block on your span

```
<span v-if="report_info.accepted && report_info.accepted_by !== null" 
  style="position:relative;display:inline-block;">
    {{ memberById(report_info.accepted_by).callsign }}
    <img style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
      width:100%;height:auto;" src="web path to img file"/>
</span>
```

Comment: How would that look?

Comment: i edited my answer to include the code, you'll need to provide the correct value of the img src attribute

Comment: Hi again, this worked well. Thank you. I'd like the image to center on the text if possible. Like now the text is at the top left corner of the image, I'd like that to be in the center. Thanks

Comment: You could switch the img to height:100%;width:auto; if that looks closer to what you're going for